# Validate IPA before upload

Tags: ios, xcode, codesign

I resigned `IPA` file with updated `provisioning profile` and I would like to validate it to confirm that everything has been done properly. However, `xcode` in organizer allows to validate only `xcarchive` not `IPA`.

Is there any way to validate `IPA` from `Terminal` or `Xcode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running altool from the terminal:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/altool 
-v -f YourApp.ipa -u <username> -p <password>
```

The help for altool:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/altool -h

Copyright (c) 2009-2018, Apple Inc. Version 1.1.1138

Usage: altool --validate-app -f <file> -t <platform> -u <username> [-p <password>]
       altool --upload-app -f <file> -t <platform> -u <username> [-p <password>]
       altool --notarize-app -f <file> --primary-bundle-id <bundle_id> -u <username> [-p <password>] [--asc-provider <provider_shortname>]
       altool --notarization-info <uuid> -u <username> [-p <password>]
       altool --notarization-history <page> -u <username> [-p <password>] [--asc-provider <provider_shortname>]

 -f, --file <file>                  <file> specifies the path to the file to process.
 -t, --type {osx | ios | appletvos} Specify the platform of the file.
 -u, --username <username>          Username. Required to connect for validation, upload, and notarization.
 -p, --password <password>          Password. Required if username specified.
                                    If this argument is not supplied on the command line, it will be read from stdin.
                                    Alternatively to entering <password> in plaintext, it may also be specified using a '@keychain:'
                                    or '@env:' prefix followed by a keychain password item name or environment variable name.
                                    Example: '-p @keychain:<name>' uses the password stored in the keychain password item named <name>
                                                                   and whose Account value matches the user name specified
                                    Example: '-p @env:<variable>'  uses the value in the environment variable named <variable>

     --primary-bundle-id <bundle_id> Used with --notarize-app to uniquely identify a package.

     --asc-provider <provider_shortname> Required with --notarize-app and --notarization-history when a user account is associated with multiple
                                         providers.
-v, --validate-app                 Validates an app archive for the App Store. The username, password, and file path to the app archive are required.

 --upload-app                   Uploads the given app archive to the App Store. The username, password, and file path to the app archive are required.

     --notarize-app                 Uploads the given app package, dmg or zip file for notarization. The file path to the package, user name,
                                    password, and --primary-bundle-id are required. --asc-provider is required for an account associated with multiple providers.
                                    If successful, the UUID associated with the upload is returned.

     --notarization-info <uuid>     Returns the status and log file URL of a package previously uploaded for notarization with the specified uuid.
                                    The user name and password are required. The log file can be retrieved with 'curl <log_file_url>'.

     --notarization-history <page>  Returns a list of all uploads submitted for notarization. <page> specifies a range of entries where 0
                                    returns the most recent number of entries. A new page value will be returned which can be used as the
                                    <page> value to the next use of --notarization-history and so forth until no more items are returned. The user name
                                    and password are required. --asc-provider is required for an account associated with multiple providers.

     --output-format {xml | normal} Specifies how the output is formatted. 'xml' displays the output in a structured format; 'normal' displays in
                                    an unstructured format (default).

 -h, --help                         Display this output.
```